# error : The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation-drawer

I am new to flutter and I get the error:

```
error : The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()'
```

I built a meal app.

I added a simple `Drawer()`.
I get the error when I open the drawer.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:recipes/screens/filters_screen.dart';

class MainDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget buildListTile(String title, IconData icon, Function tapHandler) {
    return ListTile(
        leading: Icon(
          icon,
          size: 26,
        ),
        title: Text(
          title,
          style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'RobotoCondensed',
              fontSize: 24,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        onTap:tapHandler
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
        child: Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 120,
          width: double.infinity,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
          child: Text(
            'Cooking up!',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                fontSize: 30,
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        buildListTile('Meals', Icons.restaurant,()  {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/');
        }),
        buildListTile('Filters', Icons.settings, ()  {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(FiltersScreen.routeName);
        }),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try to specify the type of `tapHandler` in your `buildListTile` method?

```dart
  Widget buildListTile(String title, IconData icon, void Function() tapHandler) {
/* ... The rest of your method */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dart has support for strong function types. This means that, in addition to the type `Function`, you can also specify the types of the parameters and return type in your function type. For example:

```dart
String example(int i) => 'Hello $i';

var String Function(int) function = example;
```

The error you are getting when you pass `tapHandler` to `ListTile.onTap` is basically saying: "I need a function that takes no parameters, and returns `void`, but you gave me any function".

For example, you could call:

```dart
buildListTile('example', Icons.add, (String s) => null)
```

which is not a `void Function()` as `ListTile` requires.

To fix it, change `buildListTile` to:

```
Widget buildListTile(String title, IconData icon, void Function() tapHandler) ...
```